# How to set the first child element's radio_button checked in rails4?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using rails4. I have a dropdown of a list. I want to check the radio_button of the first child element. Items in the dropdown list is parent and on selection of each parent a list is shown that is children.All child elements are displayed via loop, then with the help of javascript, I am displaying only those child elements which belongs to the selected parent from the dropdown.

Template
onchanging parent_id, " $("select[id='parent_<%=@parent.id%>']").change" is called then the child element in template are:-

```
<div class="child<%= @parent.id %>" style="display:none">           
    <%=radio_button :child_name, @parent.id, child.name ,id: "child"%><%=child.name%>

</div>

$("select[id='parent_<%=@parent.id%>']").change(function(){ 
    $(".child"+ this.value).each(function(){
        $(this).show();
        $(this).firstElementChild.setAttribute("checked","checked"); //Its not working
     });

});
```

Comment: since you are looping, how about the `checked: (index == 1)` in f.radio_button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Instead
// $(this).firstElementChild.setAttribute("checked","checked"); 
$(this).children().first().attr("checked", true);
```